# Selecting and building a Control from a control library dynamically, using the control name from a table

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, controls

I have a custom DDL that lives in my Server control library.

Currently I add this control to a table by strongly typing the name of the control, the customary way.

```
Control_Library.Report_NumberDDL newDDL = new Control_Library.Report_NumberDDL();
```

What I want to be able to do is dynamically create that control by pulling the control name from a table.

So I would have the name of the control in my code, in this case "Report_NumberDDL", and I would like to then create the control without having to strongly type it.

Something like this, though I know this doesn't work:

```
string controlName = "Report_NumberDDL";

Control_Library."controlName" controlNum1 = new Control_Library."controlName"();
```

SO since that obviously doesn't work can somebody help me with what would work?

Thanks

Edit:

I tried to do this:

```
    Type type = Type.GetType("Control_Library.Report_NumberDDL");
    object control = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

But on the CreateInstance(type) I get a null value exception.  So the Type isn't getting created correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use reflection to dynamically instantiate objects.  Import the System.Reflection namespace, then do something like this:

```
Type type = Type.GetType(ControlName); 
object control = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Comment: Ok I'm trying to work through this but having an issue here is what I did:

            Type type = Type.GetType("One_Eva_Control_Library.Emu_AIR_Report_NumberDDL");
            object control = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

Now I get a null type exception so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong there.

Comment: Make sure that your One_Eva_Control_Library assembly is loaded and available.  Then try Type type = Type.GetType("Emu_AIR_Report_NumberDDL");

Comment: When you say loaded and available does that simply mean adding the 'using One_Eva_Control_Library;' to my aspx.cs file?  Or is there something else need to make sure the assembly is loaded and available.

Comment: I found this, too: http://blogs.msdn.com/haibo_luo/archive/2005/08/21/454213.aspx  If you use typeof(One_Eva_Control_Library.Emu_AIR_Report_NumberDDL).AssemblyQualifiedName, you should get the string to use for GetType().

Comment: I just mean that the assembly is referenced in your project and that you have a using statement for it at the top of your class file. I'm looking at code I use to load types for a plug-in system, and I load the assemblies through reflection as well, using Assembly.LoadFile().  I think getting that AssemblyQualifiedName is going to be your best bet.